# Scissor character shown in Java JFolder (not shown in Windows Explorer)

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

Java JFileChooser showing Scissors character, what are they ?

[image]

Not displayed when use Windows Explorer itself, never seen this before.

[image]

The folder is on a USB stick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the screen shots from Windows, you see "Bullet Points" where the "Scissor" is shown in the Java representation.

Therefore I assume that the "Bullet Point" and the "Scissor" will have the same character code, but Windows and Java are using different encodings, therefore resulting in different glyphs to be displayed.

Comment: thx didnt notice that , sounds like a bug in Java ?

Comment: Or a bug in Windows? That's a common issue when different encodings collide. Which encoding is the "correct" one is a matter of taste or however you want to name it. Java is usually using UTF-8, while the Windows encoding is Windows-1252 in most Western countries.

Comment: Its clear that the original filename as created was intended to be the one with the bullet points, I thought when using JFileChooser the encodng  would be provided by the OS.